# org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: table is not mapped

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql

I am facing exeception as:

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: user is not mapped [select s.SubscriptionsId,s.SubscriptionName, s.ChamberOfCommerce, s.AccountingFirmId,(select SubscriptionName from subscriptions where SubscriptionsId=s.AccountingFirmId) as AFName,(select ChamberOfCommerce from subscriptions where SubscriptionsId=s.AccountingFirmId) as AFChamberOfCommerce,(select FtpFolder from subscriptions where SubscriptionsId=s.AccountingFirmId) as FtpFolder from user u,subscriptions s, usersubscriptions us where u.openID=:openId and u.UserId=us.UserId and us.SubscriptionsId = s.SubscriptionsId]
```

My code is as follows:

```
Query query = this.getSession().createQuery(
    this.getQuery("com.yob.sbs.dpc.getSubsctionByOpenId"))
        .setParameter("openId", openId);
```

I am using hibernate query with key `com.yob.sbs.dpc.getSubsctionByOpenId`. And my query is as follows:

```
com.yob.sbs.dpc.getSubsctionByOpenId = 
select 
    s.SubscriptionsId,
    s.SubscriptionName,
    s.ChamberOfCommerce,
    s.AccountingFirmId,
    (select SubscriptionName from subscriptions where
         SubscriptionsId = s.AccountingFirmId) as AFName,
    (select ChamberOfCommerce from subscriptions where
         SubscriptionsId = s.AccountingFirmId) as AFChamberOfCommerce,
    (select FtpFolder from subscriptions where 
         SubscriptionsId = s.AccountingFirmId) as FtpFolder 
from user u, subscriptions s, usersubscriptions us 
where 
    u.openID = :openId and 
    u.UserId = us.UserId and 
    us.SubscriptionsId = s.SubscriptionsId
```

and User data object is as follows:

```
package com.yob.dps.dataobjects;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;
import org.hibernate.validator.Length;
import org.hibernate.validator.NotEmpty;
import org.hibernate.validator.NotNull;

import com.yob.dps.vo.UserRolesVO;
import com.yob.dps.vo.UserVO;

/**
 * User.
 * Created by First Base Business Architect: Automation of Software Development
 * 
 * @author - vyankatesh.deshmukh
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User extends BaseModel implements Serializable, Comparable<User>,
        Cloneable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /** primary key */
    private String userId;

    private String firstName;

    private String middleName;

    private String lastName;

    private String phoneNumber;

    private String mobileNumber;

    private String openID;

    private String emailId;

    private String status;

    private Date createdDateTime;

    private Date updatedDateTime;

    private UserRoles userRoles;

    private Set<Subscriptions> subscriptionses = new HashSet<Subscriptions>(0);

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="usersubscriptions", catalog="scanbook", joinColumns = { 
    @JoinColumn(name="UserId", nullable=false, updatable=false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { 
    @JoinColumn(name="SubscriptionsId", nullable=false, updatable=false) })
    @Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE })
    public Set<Subscriptions> getSubscriptionses() {
        return this.subscriptionses;
    }

    public void setSubscriptionses(Set<Subscriptions> subscriptionses) {
        this.subscriptionses = subscriptionses;
    }


/**
   * Getter for property userId.
   * 
   * @return value of property userId
   */
  @Id
  @Column(name = "UserId", unique = true, nullable = false)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  public String getUserId()
  {
    return this.userId;
  }

    /**
     * Setter for property userId.
     * 
     * @param userId
     *            new value of property userId
     */
    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for property firstName.
     * 
     * @return value of property firstName
     */
    @Column(name = "firstName", length = 255, nullable = false)
    @NotEmpty
    @Length(max = 255)
    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for property firstName.
     * 
     * @param firstName
     *            new value of property firstName
     */
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for property middleName.
     * 
     * @return value of property middleName
     */
    @Column(name = "middleName", length = 255, nullable = true)
    @Length(max = 255)
    public String getMiddleName() {
        return this.middleName;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for property middleName.
     * 
     * @param middleName
     *            new value of property middleName
     */
    public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
        this.middleName = middleName;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for property lastName.
     * 
     * @return value of property lastName
     */
    @Column(name = "lastName", length = 255, nullable = false)
    @NotEmpty
    @Length(max = 255)
    public String getLastName() {
        return this.lastName;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for property lastName.
     * 
     * @param lastName
     *            new value of property lastName
     */
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for property phoneNumber.
     * 
     * @return value of property phoneNumber
     */
    @Column(name = "phoneNumber", length = 55, nullable = true)
    @Length(max = 55)
    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return this.phoneNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for property phoneNumber.
     * 
     * @param phoneNumber
     *            new value of property phoneNumber
     */
    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for property mobileNumber.
     * 
     * @return value of property mobileNumber
     */
    @Column(name = "mobileNumber", length = 55, nullable = true)
    @Length(max = 55)
    public String getMobileNumber() {
        return this.mobileNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for property mobileNumber.
     * 
     * @param mobileNumber
     *            new value of property mobileNumber
     */
    public void setMobileNumber(String mobileNumber) {
        this.mobileNumber = mobileNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for property openID.
     * 
     * @return value of property openID
     */
    @Column(name = "openID", length = 255, nullable = true)
    @Length(max = 255)
    public String getOpenID() {
        return this.openID;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for property openID.
     * 
     * @param openID
     *            new value of property openID
     */
    public void setOpenID(String openID) {
        this.openID = openID;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for property emailId.
     * 
     * @return value of property emailId
     */
    @Column(name = "emailId", length = 255, nullable = false)
    @NotEmpty
    @Length(max = 255)
    public String getEmailId() {
        return this.emailId;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for property emailId.
     * 
     * @param emailId
     *            new value of property emailId
     */
    public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for property status.
     * 
     * @return value of property status
     */
    @Column(name = "status", length = 1, nullable = true)
    @Length(max = 1)
    public String getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for property status.
     * 
     * @param status
     *            new value of property status
     */
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for property createdDateTime.
     * 
     * @return value of property createdDateTime
     */
    @Column(name = "createdDateTime", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    public Date getCreatedDateTime() {
        return this.createdDateTime;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for property createdDateTime.
     * 
     * @param createdDateTime
     *            new value of property createdDateTime
     */
    public void setCreatedDateTime(Date createdDateTime) {
        this.createdDateTime = createdDateTime;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for property updatedDateTime.
     * 
     * @return value of property updatedDateTime
     */
    @Column(name = "updatedDateTime", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    public Date getUpdatedDateTime() {
        return this.updatedDateTime;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for property updatedDateTime.
     * 
     * @param updatedDateTime
     *            new value of property updatedDateTime
     */
    public void setUpdatedDateTime(Date updatedDateTime) {
        this.updatedDateTime = updatedDateTime;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for property userRoles.
     * 
     * @return value of property userRoles
     */
    @JoinColumn(name = "UserRolesId", referencedColumnName = "UserRolesId", nullable = false)
    @OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
    public UserRoles getUserRoles() {
        return this.userRoles;
    }

    /**
     * Setter for property userRoles.
     * 
     * @param userRoles
     *            new value of property userRoles
     */
    public void setUserRoles(UserRoles userRoles) {
        this.userRoles = userRoles;
    }

    /**
     * constructor - Default constructor which loads defaults by using method loadDefaults
     */
    public User() {
        this(true);
    }

    /**
     * constructor - Constructor with option to load defaults
     * 
     * @param loadDefaults
     */
    public User(boolean loadDefaults) {
        if (loadDefaults) {
            loadDefaults();
        }
    }

    /**
     * constructor - Constructor with primary key as parameter
     * 
     * @param userId
     */
    public User(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }



    /**
     * equals -
     * 
     * @param other
     * @return boolean
     */
    public boolean equals(final Object other) {
        if (other == null)
            return false;
        if (this == other)
            return true;
        if (!(other instanceof User))
            return false;

        final User user = (User) other;
        if (this.userId != null && user.getUserId() != null) {
            return equalsByPK(user);
        } else {
            return equalsByBK(user);
        }
    }

    /**
     * equalsByPK - Return true if primary keys are equal (and not 0), otherwise false
     * 
     * @param user
     * @return boolean
     */
    public boolean equalsByPK(final User user) {
        return this.getUserId().equals(user.getUserId());
    }

    /**
     * equalsByBK - Returns true if all required attribures are equal, otherwise return false
     * 
     * @param user
     * @return boolean
     */
    public boolean equalsByBK(final User user) {
        if (this.getFirstName() != null
                && !this.getFirstName().equals(user.getFirstName()))
            return false;
        if (this.getLastName() != null
                && !this.getLastName().equals(user.getLastName()))
            return false;
        if (this.getEmailId() != null
                && !this.getEmailId().equals(user.getEmailId()))
            return false;
        if (this.getCreatedDateTime() != null
                && !this.getCreatedDateTime().equals(user.getCreatedDateTime()))
            return false;
        if (this.getUpdatedDateTime() != null
                && !this.getUpdatedDateTime().equals(user.getUpdatedDateTime()))
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * hashCode -
     * 
     * @return integer
     */
    public int hashCode() {
        int result;
        if (getUserId() != null) {
            // fast and reliable: when there's a primary key, use it as hashcode
            result = getUserId().hashCode();
        } else {
            result = 14;
            if (firstName != null)
                result = 29 * result + this.getFirstName().hashCode();
            if (middleName != null)
                result = 29 * result + this.getMiddleName().hashCode();
            if (lastName != null)
                result = 29 * result + this.getLastName().hashCode();
            if (phoneNumber != null)
                result = 29 * result + this.getPhoneNumber().hashCode();
            if (mobileNumber != null)
                result = 29 * result + this.getMobileNumber().hashCode();
            if (openID != null)
                result = 29 * result + this.getOpenID().hashCode();
            if (emailId != null)
                result = 29 * result + this.getEmailId().hashCode();
            if (status != null)
                result = 29 * result + this.getStatus().hashCode();
            if (createdDateTime != null)
                result = 29 * result + this.getCreatedDateTime().hashCode();
            if (updatedDateTime != null)
                result = 29 * result + this.getUpdatedDateTime().hashCode();

            if (userRoles != null)
                result = 17 * result + userRoles.hashCode();
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * toString -
     * 
     * @return String
     */
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("User: ");

        result.append("firstName=" + firstName);

        result.append(", ");

        result.append("middleName=" + middleName);

        result.append(", ");

        result.append("lastName=" + lastName);

        result.append(", ");

        result.append("phoneNumber=" + phoneNumber);

        result.append(", ");

        result.append("mobileNumber=" + mobileNumber);

        result.append(", ");

        result.append("openID=" + openID);

        result.append(", ");

        result.append("emailId=" + emailId);

        result.append(", ");

        result.append("status=" + status);

        result.append(", ");

        result.append("createdDateTime=" + createdDateTime);

        result.append(", ");

        result.append("updatedDateTime=" + updatedDateTime);

        return result.toString();
    }

  /**
   * copyInto -
   * 
   * @param targetUser
   */
  public void copyInto(final UserVO targetUser)
  {
    targetUser.setFirstName(this.getFirstName());
    targetUser.setMiddleName(this.getMiddleName());
    targetUser.setLastName(this.getLastName());
    targetUser.setPhoneNumber(this.getPhoneNumber());
    targetUser.setMobileNumber(this.getMobileNumber());
    targetUser.setOpenID(this.getOpenID());
    targetUser.setEmailId(this.getEmailId());
    targetUser.setStatus(this.getStatus());
    targetUser.setCreatedDateTime(this.getCreatedDateTime());
    targetUser.setUpdatedDateTime(this.getUpdatedDateTime());
    targetUser.setUserId(this.getUserId());
    UserRolesVO userRolesVO=new UserRolesVO(); 
    /*Set<SubscriptionsVO> subScSet=new HashSet<SubscriptionsVO>();
        try {
            for(Subscriptions subscriptions:this.getSubscriptionses()){
                SubscriptionsVO subscriptionsVO=new SubscriptionsVO();
                BeanUtils.copyProperties(subscriptionsVO,subscriptions);
                subScSet.add(subscriptionsVO);
            }
            targetUser.setSubscriptionses(subScSet);*/
    try {
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(userRolesVO,this.getUserRoles());
        targetUser.setUserRoles(userRolesVO);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

    /**
     * createLabel - Create a short representation of User which
     * can be used in combo's
     * 
     * @param messages
     * @return String
     */
    @Transient
    public String createLabel(final Map<String, String> messages) {
        String result;
        result = messages.get("user.label.format");
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * loadDefaults - load default values of some fields
     */
    public void loadDefaults() {

    }

}
```

But after executing the program I am getting above mentioned exception.

What is wrong in my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: just a wild guess, maybe user it's users.

Comment: We won't be able to help you without taking a look over a mapping. Please post `User` class.

Comment: @Alexey Malev Added User class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the problem is `from` clause. You should capitalize your entity names, and entity names and properties are case-sensitive in JPQL:

```
....
from User u, Subscriptions s, UserSubscriptions us 
where     
....
```

Also you're likely to encounter problem with property names. In your query all them are capitalized:

```
where 
    u.openID = :openId and 
    u.UserId = us.UserId and
```

But, JPA provider most likely will expect `userId`, not `UserId`.

Answer (score -1):

Add the User table mapping in `hibernate.cfg.xml` like so:

```
<hibernate-mapping>................
<mapping class="com.model.User"></mapping>
```

Comment: @Sirisha - Tip: XML is not visible in the browser unless you use the code button `{}` in the toolbar OR indent the line with four (4) spaces.